# Angular Routing "Cannot match any routes. Url Segment 'Home/Index'."

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-routing, angular-routing

my friends. I am very much trying and all the same i didn't get the solution of that trouble.

Trouble: 
When i am writing address 'localhost:2352/home/index' in address bar i am getting error that in title the question. But when i click at my link with the same address, that works perfect.

File app.routing.ts. I am use ASP.NET Web Api, if it's important.

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { CartsComponent } from './Components/carts.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home/index', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'home/carts', component: CartsComponent },
    {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'index', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'carts', component: CartsComponent }            
        ]
    }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I did some changes in app.routing.ts, how recommended in comments, but that still doesn't works.

File app.routing.ts:

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { CartsComponent } from './Components/carts.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [    
    {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'index', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'carts', component: CartsComponent }            
        ]
    },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

export const Routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

File app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Routing } from './app.routing';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { CartsComponent } from './Components/carts.component';

import { ProductService } from './Service/product.service'
import { CartService } from './Service/cart.service'

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, Routing, Ng2Bs3ModalModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, CartsComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, ProductService, CartService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try accessing `http://localhost:2352/#/home` instead

Comment: Also, make `{ path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },` to be the very last route in the list

Comment: Last thing, why do you need `{ path: 'home', children: [...] }` if you already have declared `{ path: 'home/index', component: HomeComponent }` and `{ path: 'home/carts', component: CartsComponent },` which seem to target same routes?

Comment: What does your `app.module` look like?

Comment: Igor Soloydenko, i am changed my file app.routing.ts, how you recommended me, but that still doesn't solve my trouble.